# How to join a realtime stream and a delayed stream by event time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to join 2 streams using `CoProcessFunction`. One of the input stream A is generated in realtime. However the other input stream B is loaded by a daily scheduled job with 1 day delay, meaning the event that is put in the stream today always has event time from yesterday.

With that being said, stream B's watermark will always be ~1 day behind A's watermark, so I would imagine a lot of events from A will be buffered in the memory. I am wondering if there is a way to solve issue. Some additional background, both stream A and B are kinesis streams(I am using `FlinkKinesisConsumer`) with retention period = 7 days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can You tell more/ perhaps provide an example of how does the join look like ? Do You want to join timestamp with equal/lower timestamp from B ?

Comment: Sure, just give a simplified example: events in both streams have a field ```dataId```, so for given event ```X``` in stream B(the delayed one), I want to find 0 or multiple events in stream A with the same ```dataId``` and also with event time no late than 5 minutes after the event time of event ```X```.

Comment: And what is the expectation from the mechanism ? You don't want any buffering ?

Comment: I understand unprocessed events will be buffered in the memory and in my case events from stream A generated in current day will be buffered. I am just concern ed about the application may run out of memory and crash.

Answer (score 0):

If You worry about the memory when buffering multiple elements, then You should take look at various different [state backends](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/state_backends.html) especially RocksDb. This way, state will be kept on disk and not in memory.

This should easily allow solving the problem You are facing with buffering elements for one day since the only thing that limits the state size is disk space available, which is generally cheap and shouldn't be a problem in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since Flink 1.8.1 the Flink Kinesis consumer has supported event-time alignment (selectively reading from splits to make sure that the various consumers advance evenly in event time). See [Event Time Alignment for Shard Consumers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kinesis.html#event-time-alignment-for-shard-consumers) for details.

The Flink community is working on providing more general support for event time synchronization across sources so that it will become possible to efficiently implement event time joins in cases like this where there is significant event time misalignment between the sources. Right now the only solution (unless you are using Kinesis) is use Flink state to buffer the stream that is ahead, which can lead to very large checkpoints and significant backpressure.

The underpinnings for general-purpose event time alignment are being implemented as part of [FLIP-27](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-27%3A+Refactor+Source+Interface) / [FLINK-10740](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10740), after which the sources will have to be re-worked to take advantage of this new mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I read the event time alignment section and my understanding is I can control how to synchronize multiple watermarks across different shards within the same kinesis stream, but in terms of syncing the consumption rates across multiple kinesis streams, how can I do that besides buffering in Flink state?

Answer (score 0):

I think the situation you are facing may not actually be a problem, assuming that your 'fast' stream comes in via something like Kafka which can act as a buffer and retain the messages. (If this is not the case, it should be straightforward to write to Kafka before joining to create this situation yourself)

Though I did not test it, I would expect the fast stream to be ingested until the buffers that are available inside Flink are full. At that point it will simply stop or slow the ingestion until the second slow stream comes in to 'clean up' all the messages that are waiting to be joined, after which the fast stream could start moving again.

Note that this may require the messages in both streams to come in roughly in the same order.